# Sort ArrayList of strings by length difference

Tags: java, arraylist, sorting

I want to order an ArrayList of strings by length, but not just in numeric order.

Say for example, the list contains these words:

```
cucumber
aeronomical
bacon
tea
telescopic
fantasmagorical
```

They need to be ordered by their difference in length to a special string, for example:

```
intelligent
```

So the final list would look like this (difference in brackets):

```
aeronomical     (0)
telescopic      (1)
fantasmagorical (3) - give priority to positive differences? doesn't really matter
cucumber        (3)
bacon           (6)
tea             (8)
```

Comment: As noted in a link-only answer, this can be accomplished with [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), which takes an explicit [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a custom comparator:

```
public class MyComparator implements java.util.Comparator<String> {

    private int referenceLength;

    public MyComparator(String reference) {
        super();
        this.referenceLength = reference.length();
    }

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int dist1 = Math.abs(s1.length() - referenceLength);
        int dist2 = Math.abs(s2.length() - referenceLength);

        return dist1 - dist2;
    }
}
```

Then sort the list using `java.util.Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`.

Comment: Priority to positive differences can be given by multiplying positive differences by two, and negative differences by negative two, then adding one.

Comment: You should make referenceLength final.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using java 8 you can also try using this lambda

```
packages.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Java 8+ you can use a lambda expression to implement (@Barend's answer as) the comparator

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cucumber","aeronomical","bacon","tea","telescopic","fantasmagorical"});
strings.sort((s1, s2) -> Math.abs(s1.length() - "intelligent".length()) - Math.abs(s2.length() - "intelligent".length()));
```

Comment: Best solution for Java 8+. Short and precise.

Comment: In case you just want to sort by length: `strings.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length());`

Answer (score 5):

- String in Ascending order

```java
class StringLengthListSort implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.length() - s2.length();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringLengthListSort ss = new StringLengthListSort();
    list.add("ram");
    list.add("rahim");
    list.add("ramshyam");
    Collections.sort(list, ss);
    System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd do this with the version of [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that takes an explicit [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem solved by lambda expression:

```
listBeforeSorting.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.length() - s2.length());
```

This way, we will get sorted-by-length(ascending order) list.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.sort(list, (a, b)->Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length()));
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of a custom comparator is correct. This is one way to implement it:

```
    Comparator c = new Comparator<String>()
    {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(results, c);
    return results;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple with Java8 solution with Comparator and Method reference only:
Stream.of(list).flatMap(Collection::stream).sorted( Comparator.comparing( String::length)).collect(toList());

Answer (score 0):

```
The shortest code for this-

public static void main(String... str) {
        List.of("am", "I", "Best", "the").stream().sorted((a, b) -> a.length() - b.length())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("geeksforgeeks", "geeksfor", "geeks");
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
       public int compare(String s1, String s2){
                return s1.length() - s2.length();
       }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Sort the list of string by length using java8**

```
String[] strArr = { "Apples","CSS", "HTML", "Oracle", "Dart"};
    
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(strArr).stream().sorted( (str1,str2) ->  str1.length() - str2.length()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(result); // output in Ascending Order : [CSS, HTML, Dart, Apples, Oracle]
```