# Can I use Collections.sort with a quasiorder?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, preorder

A total quasiorder (also called a total preorder) is a kind of weaker ordering relation, where it is allowed that two different elements are considered to be "the same size". For example, the set of all strings is quasi-ordered by length, since two different strings can have the same length.

Now assume we have a list of Strings and we want to sort it by length (shortest first). If two strings have the same length, we do not care which comes first.
At first glance, it seems reasonable to write

```
Collections.sort(list, (s, t) -> s.length() - t.length());
```

Unfortunately, this is illegal. The Javadoc of the Comparator interface demands in no unclear terms that the comparison must implement a total ordering. This is violated because "a".length() - "b".length() equals 0, but "a".equals("b") is false.

So, how are we supposed to do this cleanly? By cleanly I mean without introducing spurious comparisons e.g. by hashcode or by natural ordering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of strings by length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575761/sort-arraylist-of-strings-by-length)

Comment: "The Javadoc of the Comparator interface demands in no unclear terms that the comparison must implement a total ordering. " What gives you that impression?  This is a total ordering; it's just that elements not equal according to `.equals` can be equal according to the comparator.  That is not just legal, but perfectly normal.  It is simply not "consistent with equals."

Comment: I think you are confusing "total ordering" and "strict total ordering"

Comment: Not really related to your question, but we should avoid using `s.length() - t.length()` as result of comparing. It is true that we are safe when dealing with positive values (like in this case), but for negative ones result can overflow from negative to positive which can be a problem. It is better to use `Integer.compare(s.length(), t.length())` instead. BTW Instead of `(s, t) -> Integer.compare(s.length(), t.length())` we can use probably little clearer `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)`.

Comment: @John Graham: A total order must satisfy the antisymmetry axiom: if a <= b and b <= a then a = b. See the Wikipedia article on total order. So, ordering strings by length is not a total order (it is total, but not an order).

Answer (score 1):

Your solution that uses length does provide [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

What you are referring to by `"a".length() - "b".length() == 0`, but `"a".equals("b") == false` is not total ordering. It has to do with *being consistent with equals*. On that point, the [documentation for the Comparable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) says:

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.

This doesn't mean that you **have** to provide a comparator that will be consistent with equals.

Comment: Ok, I am not strictly required to provide a comparator that will be consistent with equals. But if I do  not then I am threatened with "Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map).  If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of equals."  So, it seems dirty to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the docs.  When they say

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects.

that's a *definition*, not a *requirement*.  For a given `Comparator`, `c`, if `c.compare(o1, o2) == 0`, then *for the purposes of the order defined by `c`*, `o1` and `o2` are equal.

The docs go on to talk about what it means for a `Comparator` to be "consistent with equals", which basically means that the sense of equality inherent in the `Comparator`, as described above, is the same as the one inherent in the permitted objects' `equals()` methods.  That discussion is predicated on the possibility that some `Comparator`s will not have that characteristic, which your proposed one doesn't.  Using such a `Comparator` to order a `SortedSet` or a `SortedMap` can produce behavior that violates the contracts of those interfaces, but there's nothing wrong with using such a `Comparator` with `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Thanks, I was beginning to suspect that. I think you are right.